# Netlogo - dynamically choose the different global variables

Tags: global-variables, netlogo

I am modelling a warehouse queuing system. The main agents are the parcels and sorting machines. Parcels are pulled from a specific named buffer queue (e.g. q-1,q-2, q-3...q-n) by the sorting machines for sorting. I do not want to model the buffer queue as agents, instead I would like to represent them as the global list variables.

The problem is how I could set the sorting machines as being able to dynamically identify and operate on the different specific global variable (q-1, q-2 ...q-n)?

Comment: There's not enough detail here for me to completely understand what you are trying to do, but I think you want to have NetLogo convert a string (that you would dynamically construct) into an executable command. If so, have a a look at `run` and `runresult` in the NetLogo dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do not want to model the buffer queue as agents

Why?

I'm sure you have your reasons, but they might be worth reconsidering.

Whenever I see variable names like `q-1`, `q-2`...`q-n`, I recoil in horror. You are trying to model something that is, conceptually, a *collection* of things. Single variables are meant to refer to single things. Programming languages have data structures meant to represent collections of things, and those are generally the right tool for the job.

In NetLogo, those data structures are (mainly) agentsets and lists.

My intuition tells me that the right approach would be to model queues as turtles owning a list variable, but if you really don't want to do that, you can always use a global list of lists to store your queues. Here is an example:

```
globals [ queues ]

to setup
  clear-all
  set queues n-values 3 [ (list) ] ; create three empty queues
  add-to-queue 0 "A"
  add-to-queue 0 "B"
  add-to-queue 1 "X"
  print queues
  print poll-from-queue 0
  print queues
end

to add-to-queue [ queue-index new-item ]
  let old-queue item queue-index queues
  let new-queue lput new-item old-queue
  set queues replace-item queue-index queues new-queue
end

to-report poll-from-queue [ queue-index ]
  let old-queue item queue-index queues
  let polled-item first item queue-index queues
  let new-queue but-first old-queue
  set queues replace-item queue-index queues new-queue
  report polled-item
end
```

In your model, the queues would store parcels instead of strings, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably have a variable that you append to create a string representation of the variable, then store the global variable inside of a local variable after executing the string:

I didn't test it, but this should work:

```
let parcel-number 2
let parcel run-result (word "q-" parcel-number)
```

Alternatively

```
run (word "let parcel q-" 2)
```

See here for more information: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#run